# WPF Image Button formatting

Tags: wpf

If I create a button with an image inside, it gets blown up to much larger size than the image.

If i try to constrain the size of image, and container button, the image gets cut off:

```
<Button Background="Transparent" Width="18" Height="18" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
    <Image Width="16" Height="16" />
</Button>
```

Native image size is 16x16. Here the button is 18x18 with 0 padding, yet the image still gets cut-off on right/bottom.

how can i make the entire button be exactly the size of the image w/out any cut off?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The beauty (and curse?) of WPF is the ability to re-template controls.

You can set the template of the button something like the following (this is free hand, so you will need to tweak it a bit for your tastes):

```
        <Button x:Name="btn16x16">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                        <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/SixteenBySixteen.png" 
                               Width="16" 
                               Height="16"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

Answer (score 12):

You should remove any `Width` and `Height` settings and set the Button's `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` both to `Center` (or `Left`/`Right` or `Top`/`Bottom` resp.). By default, these properties are set to `Stretch` which makes the button stretch to the available space. Since the image is the content of the button, it also gets stretched. Something like this should work:

### Take this code example:

```
<Button Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Image Source="thePathToYourImage" Stretch="None"/> <!-- EDIT: added Stretch="None" here! -->
</Button>
```

.

---

#### The following was just meant as an *alternative* with a different result which obviously (considering your comments) is not what you want.

<strike>If you want the button to stretch, but not the image, you could also set the `Image`'s alignment properties to something other than `Stretch`. Or you could set its [`Stretch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.stretch.aspx) property to `None`. This would make the button as large as possible, but keep the image at its original size (16x16). This would work as follows:</strike>

```
<Button Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
    <Image Source="thePathToYourImage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Button>
<!-- OR: -->
<Button Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
    <Image Source="thePathToYourImage" Stretch="None"/>
</Button>
```

Comment: i didn't experience any stretching. 
by default the image was in the middle, with a lot of space between the image and button borders. 
by default the button is a lot bigger than the containing image, and there is no stretching. 

image alignment is not the issue here

Comment: Did you check my first code sample? The second one was just an alternative. You should set the *Button's* alignment properties correctly; then the Button should size to its content, i.e. the image.

Comment: yes i have.. it makes no difference. same as default. my code: 


    <Button Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
 <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="Resources/expand.png" />
    </Button>

Comment: BUT

setting horizontal alignment, and vertical alignemnt to center, AND setting image widht and button width to 16x16, brings me close!!

the only thing left is a weird border slill showing on mouse over and when containing row is selected...

Comment: You need to set the alignment on the Button, not the Image. Read gehho's original answer again.

Comment: @Sonic Soul: Did you read my answer? Or just copied some code randomly?? Please read the paragraphs before the XAML! And choose the **first** code example, not the second. I think I will edit the answer to make it even more clear...

Comment: ok, i applied the properties to the button, not the image. But there is still no difference. Not until i set width/height of image and button. 

                            <Button Click="TestGridColumnButton_Click" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                                <Image Source="Resources/expand.png" />
                            </Button>

Comment: Just checked the code in Blend. You need to set `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` of the Button to `Center`, **and** set the `Image`'s `Stretch` property to `None` because this property defaults to `Uniform` which blows up the image as far as it can. See my edited code example in my original answer for a working example.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `Button.Background` and `ImageBrush` as an exampe like this:

```
<Button Height="24" Width="24" >
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="image name or path" Stretch="Fill" TileMode="None" />
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Comment: Best way to go, I think.  But if you're using a 16x16 icon as OP states you'll have to be careful to set the button height and width to be the correct size as to not squish the image.  I do like this answer the best as I think it is the cleanest approach.

Comment: With this approach, when I hover over the image, it fades out and becomes invisible.

Comment: Mine is worse -- I just added a brand new button to an existing form -- pretty sure there's no code touching it -- but the image slowly blinks between Visible and Invisible -- maybe it's because I have the button's IsDefault set to true? -- no clue.  It's kind of crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Think [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/4963ea1d-ebdc-409c-8c57-4b3e312be488) might give people the answer they are looking for, buttons with image and no borders at all.

Comment: isnt it the same as Wonko's suggestion? I guess if all else fails, messing with control template is needed for a image button in WPF