# Convert image to a button WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I understand that i can overlay an image on a button, but is it possible that a button can take the exact size of an image? In other words, i want to get rid of the rectangular shaped button and adapt it to the size and shape of the image.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the Template of button like below:

```
    <Button >
        <Image Source="pan-left.png"/>
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

`TemplateBinding` is used to set the `Content` property in order to set the Content inside the ControlTemplate, as you can move this `ControlTemplate` to the `Resources` and can use it for multiple button and you can set the content on button itself

Comment: Somehow when i'm using this code, the image is not displayed at all. 

<Button Tag="pan-left.png" Margin="179,10,58,0" Background="Black" Foreground="white" Focusable="False">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                    <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2998294/1522991).

You can re-template the button.

```
<Button x:Name="btn16x16">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/SixteenBySixteen.png" 
                       Width="16" 
                       Height="16"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: This works. How do i get the effect of the image being "pressed" (need to show the depressed image)

Comment: Since you replaced the button template you have to reimplement all those effects (pressed, mouse over, focused, etc.) yourself in the template. There are many examples how to do that out there.

Answer (score 0):

In above code, you are hardcoding the image path. if you want to reuse the template try this code. There are 2 ways.

if you are embedding an image in project then below.

```
<Button Tag="Images\Grapes.png" Background="Black" Foreground="white" Focusable="False" Width="100" Height="30">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">                    
                <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Tag}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

if you are adding image as content in project the below code using absolute path.

```
<Button Tag="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Apple.png">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Tag}" Stretch="None" />                        
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```